# Different solution for MOSP(Mathematical Olympiad Summer Program) 2001 Test 9 Problem

Tags: geometry, contest-math

> Let $ABCD$ be a convex quadrilateral and let $O$ be the point of intersection of its
>   diagonals. Prove that
>   if the perimeters of $\triangle ABO$,$\triangle BCO$,$\triangle CDO$ and $\triangle DAO$ are equal then $ABCD$
>   is a rhombus.

first time I saw this problem on Problem-Solving Strategies book By Arthur Engel on summer(you can see this solution from this [book](http://books.google.com/books?isbn=1876420537) on page 126).this problem was in the extremal principle chapter.I wanted to find another way to prove it but I was not able to do anything useful.

I did some research and I was able to find that this problem is From MOSP 2001. But I was not able to find any other solution other than the one I saw on Arthur Engel book. Any help or hint on proving this problem in other ways are appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell us what that solution was like?

Comment: @Sawarnik what do you mean from "that" solution? the only solution i found for this problem is the one that I mentioned in [my post](http://books.google.com/books?isbn=1876420537).

Answer (score 2):

We see that $ OB + BA = OD + DA $, hence $B, D$ lie on an ellipse whose foci is $A, O$.
Similarly, since $OB + BC = OD + DC $, hence $B, D$ lie on an ellipse whose foci is $ O, C $.

Slight argument that ellipse with foci $A,O$ and $O,C$, with $AOC$ a straight line can only intersect at 2 points. Furthermore, by symmetry, these 2 points are symmetric about the line $AOC$. Thus $BD \perp AC$.

From this, it follows that $ AB = BC = CD = DA$ from the perimeter requirements, hence we have a rhombus.